# Float Material UI SwipeableDrawer component to the right using React

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, jsx

I'm working on a project utilizing material ui and React/Redux. The figma file recently changed to have the built-in SwipeableDrawer component on the right side of the screen instead of the left. No matter what I do I can't figure out how to change the position.

Here's the JSX for the component

```
 <SwipeableDrawer
      className="swipeDrawer"
      anchor="bottom"
      variant="temporary"
      open={isFilterShown}
      onOpen={toggleFilterModal}
      onClose={toggleFilterModal}
      sx={{
        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
          height: '50%'
        }
      }}
    >
      <Box
        className="filterBox"
        sx={{
          height: '14%',
          backgroundColor: '#525F75',
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          paddingTop: '5%'
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h5" color="white">
          Water Filter
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box className="filterGroup">
        <Typography className="filterFont">Features</Typography>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item>
            <FilterButton
              active={openNow}
              filter={'Open Now'}
              action={{
                type: 'SET_TOGGLE_STATE',
                toggle: 'openNow',
                toggleState: !openNow
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <FilterButton
              active={handicap}
              filter={'ADA Accessible'}
              action={{
                type: 'SET_TOGGLE_STATE',
                toggle: 'handicap',
                toggleState: !handicap
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <FilterButton
              active={sparkling}
              filter={'Sparkling'}
              action={{
                type: 'SET_TOGGLE_STATE',
                toggle: 'sparkling',
                toggleState: !sparkling
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Box className="filterGroup">
        <Typography className="filterFont">Tap Type</Typography>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item>
            <FilterButton
              active={fountain}
              filter={'Drinking Fountain'}
              action={{
                type: 'SET_TOGGLE_STATE',
                toggle: 'fountain',
                toggleState: !fountain
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <FilterButton active={soda} filter={'Soda Dispenser'} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <FilterButton active={cooler} filter={'Water Cooler'} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <FilterButton active={bottle} filter={'Bottle Filter'} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Box className="filterGroup">
        <Grid Container>
          <Typography className="filterFont">Organization Type</Typography>
          <ButtonGroup aria-label="outlined button group">
            <FilterButton active={publicOrg} filter={'Public'} />
            <FilterButton active={privateOrg} filter={'Private'} />
            <FilterButton active={sharedOrg} filter={'Shared'} />
            <FilterButton active={restrictedOrg} filter={'Restricted'} />
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Grid>
        <Grid className="bottomButtons" Container>
          <Button onClick={clearAll} className=" clearButton" variant="text">
            Clear All
          </Button>
          <Button className=" applyButton" variant="outlined">
            Apply
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </SwipeableDrawer>
```

here's the relevant CSS class that I have. I obviously don't want to do this using padding-left/padding-right because that is not responsive.

`.filterBox { width: 100%; padding-right: 0; }`

I've tried using display block/float left and that didn't work. I've honestly been working on this for over a week and tried many things that I can't remember but I've really been stuck.

edit: the end result HTML was requested.

```html
<div
  role="presentation"
  class="MuiModal-root MuiDrawer-root MuiDrawer-modal swipeDrawer css-1ggqt74-MuiModal-root-MuiDrawer-root"
>
  <div
    aria-hidden="true"
    class="MuiBackdrop-root css-i9fmh8-MuiBackdrop-root-MuiModal-backdrop"
    style="
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    "
  ></div>
  <div tabindex="0" data-test="sentinelStart"></div>
  <div
    class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-elevation16 MuiDrawer-paper MuiDrawer-paperAnchorBottom css-9emuhu-MuiPaper-root-MuiDrawer-paper"
    tabindex="-1"
    style="
      transform: none;
      transition: transform 225ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    "
  >
    <div class="filterBox MuiBox-root css-od27r6">
      <h5
        class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h5 css-1rtg20-MuiTypography-root"
      >
        Water Filter
      </h5>
    </div>
      <!-- ...  -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" data-test="sentinelEnd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the end-result HTML instead of the JSX? It is best to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to troubleshoot in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

You need just to change the `anchor` prop that is available in the component, all the `Drawer` props are inherited from the `SwipeableDrawer`:

```
<SwipeableDrawer
  anchor={'left'} // 'right', 'bottom', 'top'
  ...other props
>
  Your content here
</SwipeableDrawer>
```

There is absolutley no reason to use custom styling for the position of appearence of the `SwipeableDrawer`

Drawer demos: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/
SwipeableDrawer API: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/swipeable-drawer/